# path constraint fails

Tags: constraints, path

Im new to Blender and i have put my mind into learning all i can about this awesome program. I have done alot of tutorials on sculping and animating, and it all gone real good.
I have now made my own version of Tux and i want it to follow a path. I have put in the Key frames for its walk rotation, but when i try to do a path constraint, Tux gets seperated from the amature and i dancing around looking all weired.

You can see him here.
http://www.mediafire.com/file/f3p4pej5mje96gq/Tux+go+wrong.blend

I have now spend 3 days trying to fix it. reading forums. I have started all over and followed many toturials on the subject.

I will never give up on this, but i hope that after 3 day there is a friendly soul who could be helpfull, so i can learn this lovely program proper.

Comment: Please prefer http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com in the future for sharing files here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded your .blend file and if you remove the follow path constraint on the penguin, it should work fine!

Hope this helps!

Comment: You beat me to it

Comment: lol, I saw your comment on the question and thought "oh no, someone else! I hope they don't beat me to the answer!"

Comment: hmm.. maybe i misunderstand you. i have now removed follow path. and it walk backwards, and only half the path, while its winds are in the air.

Comment: thats because its facing backwards away from the beginning of the curve. I believe you can just rotate it around

Comment: I got it sorted now. Tux walks the right way, wings down, and follow the path around. Thanks alot for the help.. I have only spend 3 full days on this, and a few minutes after i wrote this post i got the help pi needed.. Again thanks alot.